# Running Ubuntu on an external hard drive and risk accidentally disconnecting it?

Tags: virtualization, external-hdd

I am getting a new laptop soon and unfortunately it only has 256gb ssd. I don't really want to partition it since that would leave me with a meager amount of space. I also want to keep my Windows 8.1. Therefore I am considering to either boot Ubuntu from an external hard drive or run it through a virtual machine and store the data on the external.

Which one is safer? Since the external hdd is connected via usb 3.0, there is a risk of disconnecting the usb cord during runtime and I am afraid this would cause a number of problems such as data corruption. Therefore, would a virtual machine be a safer bet? Or are there better options available?

Comment: If it were me, I'd move all the windows standard data directories (My Documents, Pictures, Downloads, etc) to the external drive (easy to do), then partition the SSD to assign 10 or 20 GB to Ubuntu, with its data also on the external drive (sharing with Windows).

Comment: Would the virtual machine be stored on the external drive or the ssd? If it's on the external then you face the same problem as natively installing it there. If it's on the ssd then it will eat up just as much space as natively installing it there.

Comment: The virtual image would be installed on the external drive. However, I was thinking maybe since it is a virtual image, it would be safer than having ubuntu directly boot from the external.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When It is a laptop, I think, it is better on using virtual machine. Because you move it as much than if it is a static PC (a Desktop one).

I used to install ubuntu on harddisk and it disconnected often when used on laptop (just by moving slightly). The system will freeze and bump! nothing to do but restarting it.

**I recommend you to use your second option**.

Ensure your `/home` dir is in laptop and other files go to external disk. Because losing (disconnecting) you `/home` will freeze it also.

Answer (score 0):

I use an external drive for Ubuntu on my Windows 7 laptop and it works great. I went into BIOS and set the boot priority to the USB port to be first, the internal HD second. So if I forget to turn the external drive on it boots into windows normally.

Since the Windows OS was present when I installed Ubuntu, when booting to the external drive, I get the Ubuntu boot menu where I can choose Windows as a alternative.

The technical part: I use an external USB3 docking device (Thermaltake Blacx) and a bare 128GB SSD. It's very fast. The ultrabook I use has an internal SSD as well. I installed from a USB2 flashdrive and selected the external drive as the destination Ubuntu boot. I've had no issues. The USB drive has never disconnected itself, and I can't imagine why it would.

Answer (score 0):

Any power interrumption can cause data corrumption..

but if you create a live usb are fast enought to store your config and install applications but whule running will primarily reside  on the memory of your computer and memory does not care if your pc goes unexpectedly off

But if you care about your external hhd. try to not interrumpt it while working. many flash drives never goes up again due to this.

and so with a VM you will be a more secure but will consume more resources and you will probably face hardware or driver limitations.

The best ever thing you can do is give to your linux  a very small partition and minimal swap space. based on your needs , choose a distro with small disk space requirement and go on.